# FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory Aborted (core dumped) - Node.js

Tags: node.js, out-of-memory

I have been getting 'FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)' error while running a nodejs process although I am using the command :

    `node --max-old-space-size=8192 run.js`

I am using v10.25.

The code simply downloads data(size=2gb) from aws s3 and there are some data manipulation associated.

Why would nodejs run out of memory?
How to run this nodejs process without the fatal error?
Any help is appreciated.

**Edit 1**:-

inspecting with 

`console.log(util.inspect(process.memoryUsage()));`

Just before crashing gives this:-

`{ rss: 1351979008, heapTotal: 1089684736, heapUsed: 1069900560 }`

Comment: Did you try your script with io.js or node v0.12.x? The version of v8 that ships with the latest releases for both should contain [a fix that properly sets the resource limits](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/detail?r=21102).

Comment: Also, are you storing the whole 2GB in memory? If so, is that really necessary?

Comment: @mscdex yeah I am storing 2GB in memory I need to do some data manipulation and send it to another database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who is facing this issue.

I installed nodejs v12.02 to use `--max-old-space-size=8192`.

It was not working in v10.25.

Comment: `--max-old-space-size=8192` it throw the `--max-old-space-size=8192: command not found`. Please update the answer with explanation

Comment: @vamsi its a console argument. `node --max-old-space-size=8192 app_name`